# TCPDF can't show cyrillic

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to output cyrillic in pdf with TCPDF .

I tried using, UTF-8, Windows-1251. I had changed the Unicode to FALSE and TRUE, to test, but I'm getting only? I tried with default and with font from file, but same results, and I tried using setsubsettings, again, no result. What is wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that your actual document, or the place you're getting the actual letters from, is not utf8?

Comment: I think it is, but how i sad, i tried couple of encodings, not only UTF-8

Answer (score 19):

Setting the font to freeserif did it for me - default/helvetica font: unreadable cyrillic characters; freeserif: readable Russian text.

```
// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);
```

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_008.phps

Answer (score 1):

Replace SetFont

```
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

use TFPDF instead.

Check the source here:
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

e.g.:

```
<?php

// Optionally define the filesystem path to your system fonts
// otherwise tFPDF will use [path to tFPDF]/font/unifont/ directory
// define("_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", "C:/Windows/Fonts/");

require('tfpdf.php');

$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// Add a Unicode font (uses UTF-8)
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

// Load a UTF-8 string from a file and print it
$txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

// Select a standard font (uses windows-1252)
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Write(5,'The file size of this PDF is only 13 KB.');

$pdf->Output();
?>
```